# BinaryFile Read to byte[]

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, binaryreader

I have binary file

```
BinaryWriter binwriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:\\temp\\Users.bin", FileMode.Create));
binwriter.Write(buff);
binwriter.Close();
```

It works, but how can I read data from this file?
I need to read new line each time, while it is not end of file.

```
BinaryReader binreader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\\temp\\Users.bin", FileMode.Open));
byte[] m = binreader.ReadBytes(??????); //I to read only 1 line to m, and then I need to read again new line to m.
```

Comment: If it's a *binary* file then there's no concept of a "line". That's specific to *text*. Please give more information.

Comment: I write to FILE arrays like m, and I want to read them, by line I mean 1 array m

Comment: No, that's not clear at all. What do you mean by a "file array"? And what do you mean by a "line" if this is arbitrary binary data? For example, imagine that the file actually contains a piece of music encoded as MP3 - what does a "line" mean in that context? It's vital that you understand the nature of your data and treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary file doesn't have the concept of a "line", however you can try to read it like a text file by doing this way :

```
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
  {
    string line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```

you can of course adapt it to your needs instead of printing it on the Console.

Comment: Why use `Peek`? It's cleaner (IMO) just to read a line at a time until `ReadLine` returns `null`. However, all of this is assuming a text file, whereas the question appears to be confused about whether the data is text or binary.

Comment: Yea it's indeed confusing, but since he was asking about reading a single line, I thought he was gonna codify his byte stream in such a way. I suggested to use Peek because it was suggested on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx.

Comment: Ick - MSDN fail again, IMO :(